# React-native > Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

I have been developing RN app for long time using IOS simulator and now I am trying to build the application in android emulator for the first time and I have this error [image]

and I have the Android development environment

Any clue what's the problem or maybe solutions?